# Corrupted windows?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, restore

In a [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1302458/computer-fails-to-boot), I described how my computer wouldn't boot. After no progress, I bought a new SSD. I restored my macrium backup image to the new SSD, and it still wouldn't boot. The computer would not recognize a boot device at all. Next, I tried a fresh windows install on the new ssd. The computer successfully booted into the windows installation.

So what exactly is going on here? Why won't the the computer boot with the old windows installation? What can I try to do to fix that? Is there another way to transfer my macrium backup image to the new installation of windows?

The previous installation and new installation are both windows 10.

Comment: When you backed up your system did you include all partitions on the drive, or just the C: drive? A booting windows operating system usually consists of more than one partition and they have to be present to work properly.

Comment: I think so but I'm not sure... anyway I can check that? I have a laptop and usb to sata that I can use to do any diagnostics. In any case, the old ssd wouldn't boot anyway without messing with any partitions

Comment: Yes, you could inspect the partitions on the drive and see if it has the windows C: partition and at least a small system partition that is set active. That’s the typical layout.

Comment: 2 partitions: Primary and Recovery, both listed as healthy

Comment: I noticed neither was set as "Active". Which one should be active?

Comment: Then it looks like you are most likely missing the boot partition necessary for Windows to boot. What you do next depends on if your system is booting UEFI or Legacy. You’ll have to restore the missing boot partition. Either MBR based, or EFI based.

Comment: Thanks. How do I figure out if UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: Are you using MBR or GPT partition scheme

Comment: I think MBR. How do I check that as well? As you can tell, I'm in over my head here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this worked but I ran

```
bcdboot N:\windows /s M:
```

with the relevant drives as described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-cant-boot/5b675a98-ac85-46f1-894a-9a8ac016caec). I ran bootrec fixmbr and fixboot after that but I don't know if those actually did actually.

and now it boots again!!!!!!!! Nothing was lost either.