# Hard drive sometimes shows as uninitialized, sometimes doesn't show at all

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, disk-management

After multiple previous issues (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1321885/corrupted-windows) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1302458/computer-fails-to-boot)), now one of my hard drives is not working properly. It is a Seagate ST2000DM001, 2TB. It shows in bios. However, it sometimes does not show up at all in windows (diskpart, disk management, anything). Other times, it shows up in Windows as an uninitialized disk. When it does show there, it shows in diskpart as having 0 size.

I have no idea what's going on...again.

Comment: Seems like your hard disk has failed. *You have backups, right?*

Comment: I thought I did but I might be wrong unfortunately :(. I think I'm going to check out some recovery services